# Angular6 create reusable html artefacts

Tags: html, angular

I am pretty new to angular, so please be patient.

I want to create a set of ui elements. Lets say, I have a section which is like this:

```
<section>
  <h2 class="section-title">Title</h2>
  <... html to make section collapsible .../>
  <div class="section-body">
    content goes here
  </div>
</section>
```

Now everytime I want to use this, I have to copy paste it...

Is it somehow possible that I create my own template for this?

```
<my-section title="Some Title" collapsible="true"> 
    content goes here 
</my-section>
```

Comment: You should try the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) from angular website. If you have already have done it, [this section](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3) could help you creating your custom component.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your code logic.

But I guess you are looking for iteration through some data, while the data in the example here is the `items`

```
<section>
  <h2 class="section-title">Title</h2>
  <... html to make section collapsible .../>
  <div class="section-body"  *ngFor="item of items">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</section>
```